# How can I do symbolic matrix calculation in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to do this calculation using Matlab symbolic calculation and I do not know how.

```
(A'+A)*x+(C+D)*x
```

and I want Matlab to simple it for me like this

```
(A+A'+C+D)*x
```

A,C and D are n*n matrices and x is a n*1 vector.

does anybody know how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html

Comment: But `A` needs to be square, right? Otherwise `A+A'` isn't defined

Comment: @Luis Mendo yes you were right. I edited my question

Comment: You mean to define a symbolic variable A and have MatLab treat it as  a matrix? Because this is not possible, as far as I know. In Matlab, a matrix is a symbolic matrix because the entries are symbolic scalars. In other words, the definition of A has to be explicit. I believe the same applies to mupad, although it supports a superset of the symbolic commands supported by Matlab. Personally, I had to resort to maxima (which is a powerful language, by the way) for some calculations in non-commutative algebra.

Answer (score 0):

You can define some symbolic expresions with the corresponding toolbox like:
     syms a ...
Alltough packing those into matricies is quite tedious and you'll soon hit some limitations.
So the best answer is use a symbolic language for symbolic calculations, like mathematica...

Comment: It is not an easy symbolic calculation it is a whole matrix symbolic calculation

Comment: I've noticed that, that's why I pointed out, that one can stack symbolic variables. But this is really like asking for extended vector capabilities in Photoshop, just not the wright program.

Comment: could you introduce some symbolic language in your answer?